# Why an understandable open problem In mathematics can not solvable?

Tags: logic, education, constructive-mathematics, open-problem

If we check the standard open problems in Mathematics which they are understandable even for a student in Midlle school as example if we take this  problem : " Is there an odd perfect number" ? it's understandable at a least for high school level or middle school but it's very hard for solving .

**My logic basic is** :any unsolvable problem never be understandable at all.

**My question here is:** Why an  understandable open problem In mathematics  can not solvable ?.

**Note:** I meant by understandable problem " popular problem "

Thank you for any help

Comment: One way is to understand the laws of math so well such that we prove it is not solvable...yet.

Comment: Your logic is like this: If I can see a star, I should be able to travel to it....

Comment: Your writing is not the most coherent, in my opinion. However, I think I get the gist of what you're asking: problems which are hard to solve should be hard to state. This, well, just isn't true. There's no real reason an easy to state problem should have an obvious solution. Many easy to state problems require a substantial amount of machinery to prove. It's just the way math is.

Comment: @N.S. thanks for nice indication , we have popular example say : understanding question is the half answer" Mayeb this is a wrong example and wrong guess

Comment: Can you understand the following claim? 'Every even number greater than 2 is the sum of two prime numbers'. While we may find the truth value to that claim sometime in the future, as of right now we don't know whether it is true or false. Some problems are easy to state, but very hard to solve.

Comment: Usually, the harder a problem is to understand, the more details there are, so the easier it is to solve.  Easy to understand problems have fewer assumptions and so are usually harder to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not giving a formal definition of "not solvable", let me give you an historical counterexample to your claim.

The quest for exact algebraic expressions giving the roots of polynomials has been a central topic in mathematics for centuries. However, as a consequence of the work of Abel, Ruffini and Galois, the solutions of the equation $x^{5}=x+1$ cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. This is a very simple example of a problem that is not solvable (by radicals).